# I am using UIBarButtonItem in navigation bar for open side menu in my project but it is don't work. Here is the code which I implemented:

Tags: ios, iphone

```
- (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}
```

Comment: Please make sure you have done basic setup properly as mentioned here : https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu

Comment: If helpful then please accept the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow this code.You will get the result.

```
- (BOOL)shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation)toInterfaceOrientation {
    return YES;
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    if(!self.title) self.title = @"Demo!";

    [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIBarButtonItems

- (void)setupMenuBarButtonItems {
    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [self rightMenuBarButtonItem];
    if(self.menuContainerViewController.menuState == MFSideMenuStateClosed &&
       ![[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:0] isEqual:self]) {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self backBarButtonItem];
    } else {
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = [self leftMenuBarButtonItem];
    }
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)leftMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(leftSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)rightMenuBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
            initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"menu-icon.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
            target:self
            action:@selector(rightSideMenuButtonPressed:)];
}

- (UIBarButtonItem *)backBarButtonItem {
    return [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back-arrow"]
                                            style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                                           target:self
                                           action:@selector(backButtonPressed:)];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - UIBarButtonItem Callbacks

- (void)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)leftSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleLeftSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}

- (void)rightSideMenuButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.menuContainerViewController toggleRightSideMenuCompletion:^{
        [self setupMenuBarButtonItems];
    }];
}


#pragma mark -
#pragma mark - IBActions

- (IBAction)pushAnotherPressed:(id)sender {
    DemoViewController *demoController = [[DemoViewController alloc]
                                          initWithNibName:@"DemoViewController"
                                          bundle:nil];

    [self.navigationController pushViewController:demoController animated:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Please make sure you have done basic setup properly as mentioned here :

https://github.com/mikefrederick/MFSideMenu